# What's idiomatic clojure for :use

Tags: clojure, idioms

I've seen several different ways for `:use` in clojure--what's the idiomatic/preferred method?

#1

```
(ns namespace.core
  (:use [[something.core]
         [another.core]]))
```

or #2 EDIT: Use this with conjunction with `:only`.

```
(ns namespace.core
  (:use [something.core]
        [another.core]))
```

or #3

```
(ns namespace.core
  (:use [something.core
         another.core]))
```

or #4

```
(ns namespace.core
  (:use (something.core
         another.core)))
```

or #5 EDIT: This is idiomatic, but one should be using `:use` as in #2

```
(ns namespace.core
  (:use something.core
        another.core))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Choice #5 is idiomatic, unless you are passing additional options such as :only, :exclude, etc. [Colin's blog post](http://blog.8thlight.com/articles/2010/12/6/clojure-libs-and-namespaces-require-use-import-and-ns) covers the options in great detail.

The API for dealing with namespaces is unnecessarily difficult to learn. However, it is certainly capable enough for a wide variety of uses, so the pressure for a rewrite has yet to reach the boiling point for anyone.

Answer (score 4):

Actually none of them are idiomatic. You should always have an :only clause in your :uses. Your best bet is adding :only to #2. If you don't want to enumerate all the vars you're taking from another namespace, consider (:require [foo.bar :as bar]).

> One point of note that we should mention is that the
>   (:use (clojure set xml)) statement is considered a promiscuous operation
>   and therefore discouraged. [...] When organizing your
>   code along namespaces, it’s good practice to export and import only those
>   elements needed.

-from the Joy of Clojure, page 183.

The one exception is that a test namespace should bare-use the namespace it tests.

Answer (score 2):

The cases 1, 3 and 4 are not valid and throw some Exception. I haven't seen 2 - only in combination with `:only` or the like.

```
(ns namespace.core
  (:use
    [something.core :only (x)]
    another.core))
```

I usually use 5.

Comment: Oops, I was looking at my project.clj :dependencies to get #1.

Answer (score 0):

In Clojure 1.4+ I wouldn't use `use` at all.  `require` can do all that `use` can do now, so forget about `use`.  One less thing to worry about.

If you want `use`-like behaviour (still bad form, imo) you can do:

```
(ns namespace.core
  (:require
    [something.core :refer :all]
    [another.core :refer :all]))
```

If you want `:use .. :only` behaviour, use:

```
(ns namespace.core
  (:require
    [something.core :refer [foo bar]]
    [another.core :refer [quux]]))
```

More detail: [In Clojure 1.4 what is the use of refer within require?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10358149/in-clojure-1-4-what-is-the-use-of-refer-within-require)