# In Clojure 1.4 what is the use of refer within require?

Tags: clojure

What advantage does using `:refer` in `:require` have over using `:only` in `:use`? Are the following synonymous?

```
(ns so.example (:use [my.lib :only [function]]))
```

and

```
(ns so.example (:require [my.lib :refer [function]]))
```

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Main idea of adding `:refer` to `:require` is to get rid completely of `:use`, leaving only one operator to load other packages. You can emulate existing `:use` with `(:require [my.lib :refer :all])`...

Comment: I understand that `:refer` allows us to get rid of `:use`, but can you point me to documentation that indicates that this was the idea? I personally think that `:use` is convenient in certain cases, such as with `clojure.test`. Why not use `:use` in such cases?

Comment: see http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-879 & link to the discussion in clojure-dev mailing list...

Answer (score 26):

yes, they are equivalent,

`:refer` and `:require` are the basic operations required to build namespaces. `:use` is more convienient

- `:require` causes classes to be loaded
- `:refer` adds things to the name space which is really just a map (actually a couple of maps)
- `:use` is `:refer` + `:require`

as much is it may look like it, there really is no magic to namespaces

if you make a namespace like this

```
(ns so.example (:use my.lib))
```

the equivalent with :require would be:

```
(ns so.example (:require [my.lib :refer [function1 function2 function3 
                                         list every function in example 
                                         here and remember to keep it 
                                         up to date ]]))
```

Comment: its almost alwasy used with :as to give short names to packages. ohh and it came first. use calls :refer, refer does not use :use

Comment: I still don't understand why `:refer` was added to `:require`. What problem has been solved that wasn't already?

Comment: Andrew, main idea of adding `:refer` to `:require` is to get rid completely from `:use`. Now you can emulate `:use` with `(:require [my.lib :refer :all])`...

Comment: @AlexOtt Thanks. If you put your comment as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

As of the 1.4.0 release, there's no longer a good reason to use use. Use require :refer instead. From the Clojure 1.4.0 changelog: "require can now take a :refer option. :refer takes a list of symbols to refer from the namespace or :all to bring in all public vars."
(from  https://8thlight.com/blog/colin-jones/2010/12/05/clojure-libs-and-namespaces-require-use-import-and-ns.html)