# What's the most idiomatic way to use the :require and :use in the ns macro

Tags: clojure

What's the most idiomatic way to use the `:require` and `:use` in the `ns` macro?

```
(ns app.core
  (:require [clojure.tools.logging :as log]
            [clojure.java.io :as io]
            [clojure.edn])
  (:use [compojure.core]
        [postal.core]
        [ring.adapter.jetty]
        [ring.middleware.multipart-params]))
```

or

```
(ns app.core
  (:require [clojure.tools.logging :as log])
  (:require [clojure.java.io :as io])
  (:require clojure.edn)
  (:use compojure.core)
  (:use postal.core)
  (:use ring.adapter.jetty)
  (:use ring.middleware.multipart-params))
```

or somehow else?

Is there any common guidelines or best practices?

Comment: Refer to the style guide: https://github.com/bbatsov/clojure-style-guide#prefer-require-over-use

Comment: I recently wrote an exhaustive guide to `ns` style: [How to ns](https://stuartsierra.com/2016/clojure-how-to-ns.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first example is more idiomatic. However, the use of `use` or `:use` is discouraged, so the most idiomatic way would be this:

```
(ns app.core
  (:require [clojure.edn]
            [clojure.java.io :as io]
            [clojure.tools.logging :as log]
            [compojure.core :refer :all]
            [postal.core :refer :all]
            [ring.adapter.jetty :refer :all]
            [ring.middleware.multipart-params :refer :all]))
```

You may find it beneficial to try to follow the [Clojure community style guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/clojure-style-guide).

Comment: What's wrong with the `:use`? It seems that `:require` combined with `:refer :all` is the same thing actually

Comment: @FrozenHeart I would encourage you to read the [many](http://stackoverflow.com/q/871997/5044950) [posts](https://8thlight.com/blog/colin-jones/2010/12/05/clojure-libs-and-namespaces-require-use-import-and-ns.html) [on](http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-879) [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10358149/5044950) [topic](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/clojure/137qrc7xmr/can-we-please-deprecate-the-use-directive).